# Update View After Destroying Item from Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Right now I am displaying notifications for a user on a view. I have the ajax working where it removes the item from the database by clicking the close link. However, what I can't figure out is how to have the view update without actually refreshing the page.

Am I going to have to use a partial of some sort? I haven't really done anything like this and googling is really not helping me since I seem to be going down the rabbit hole.

Right now for my view I have:

```
<% current_user.notifications.each do |n| %>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <%= link_to 'x', n, :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'delete_notification close'  %>
      <%= n.title %>
      <%= n.description %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and then I have my js:

```
$('.delete_notification').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
```

});

I'm not really sure how to ask the question since I am lost on what the 'next step' is. I will provide more information if/when I know what else I need to provide.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I accepted an answer seeing as it was extremely helpful and exactly what I was looking for!

What I ended up comming up with is:

```
$(function(){
  $(".delete_notification").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var url = $this.data('url');
    $.ajax(url, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() {
        var parent = $this.parent();
        parent.fadeOut("slow");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So you want to remove the deleted item from the DOM, without refreshing the page, right? so why don't you try to add this to your JavaScript `$('#deleted-item-id').remove();` or you can use `.hide()` this should do it. Give it a shot and let us know how it goes.

Comment: why to `fadeOut()` the closest `tr`? I see no `tr` in your code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `link_to`'s callback option (`:update`) is removed since Rails 3, so I'd rather implement the AJAX link myself.

```
<% current_user.notifications.each do |n| %>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <%= link_to 'x', n, :class => 'delete_notification close' %>
      <%= n.title %>
      <%= n.description %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Setup AJAX so that it passes Rails' CSRF protection:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}
});
```

And finally the effect you want:

```
$('.delete_notification').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();  // prevent refreshing page
  var $this = $(this);
  var url = $this.attr('href');
  $.ajax(url, {method: 'DELETE'}).done(function() {
    $this.closest('tr').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Maybe you should also modify your controller (I haven't tested this):

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  # Other actions ...

  def destroy
    # Your logic (remove rendering or redirection)
    head :no_content
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a js template in your view called destroy.js.erb, and in that file include the javascript you want to run - something like this:

```
$('#delete_notification_<%= params[:id] %>').closest('tr').fadeOut();
```

In your view make sure you specify the ID of the link:

```
<%= link_to 'x', n, method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'delete_notification close' id: "delete_notification_#{n.object.id}" %>
```